# MYSQL Characters like ( ', ", &) etc. appear different

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm keeping a database that is filled automaticlly by my users. but when there is an input like `My Father's Will`. It will get into the database like: `My Father&#x27;s Will`.

This is not what I want. Can someone tell me how to enable these kinds of special characters or possibly a work around to not show these ugly characters to my users.

I'm using PHP, a MySQL server and PHPMyAdmin as DB Management tool.

Comment: You need to format your post correctly. It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `'` is escaped like a HTML character. I guess you're doing a wrong escaping, like using `htmlentities` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`. If this info doesn't help, please post your code. It will be guessing without.

Comment: Is there a way to reverse this so that that "&#x27;" will become a single qoute on the page?

Comment: html_entity_decode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php It allows you to specify a character set. Make sure you choose the one that matches your database.

Answer (score 1):

When you pull the values out of your database, use htmlspecialchars_decode(). This will convert all html special characters back into regular text.

```
$str = 'My Father&#x27;s Will';
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
```

will output:

```
My Father's Will
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really figure what you are asking, since "My Father's Will" and "My Father's Will" is exactly the same?

But it seems like a problem related to either string escaping in PHP or conflicting encoding in the MySQL-database, try to have a look into both and feel free to specify you question a bit more.

Comment: Yeah edited my post... it was because this page rendered the special characters as a '

Comment: As mentioned above, this looks like an encoding or escaping problem when inserting the data using PHP. Have you tried functions like html_entity_decode() on the data before inserting into the db? [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be escaping (such as php's htmlentities()) your input on its way to the database.  The correct thing to do would be to instead escape it only on output back to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a call to `htmlspecialchars(..., ENT_QUOTES)` in your code somewhere, which would encode `'` and `"` into character entities. If they're in the database in encoded form, and the end-user sees the character entities, then you're doing a double-encoding and your script's output is something like `&amp;x27;`.